# Flush rewrite rules with scheduled event (cron)

Tags: permalinks, rewrite-rules, wp-cron, cron

I'm trying to flush rewrite rule with a `wp_schedule_event`

```
function el_custom_cron_schedule( $schedules ) {
    $schedules['el_every_5mn'] = array(
        'interval' => 5*60,
        'display'  => __( 'Every 5 minutes' ),
    );
    return $schedules;
}
add_filter( 'cron_schedules', 'el_custom_cron_schedule' );

 // Flush permalinks every 5mn
function el_flush_permalinks_activation() {
    if ( !wp_next_scheduled( 'el_5mn_event' ) ) {
        wp_schedule_event(time(), 'el_every_5mn', 'el_5mn_event');
    }
}
add_action('el_5mn_event', 'el_flush_permalinks');

add_action('wp', 'el_flush_permalinks_activation');

function el_flush_permalinks() {
    flush_rewrite_rules(true);
}
```

So the Scheduled Task works, i test it with email sending (`wp_mail` in the function `el_flush_permalinks`)

The issue is that `flush_rewrite_rules()` is not launch. i thought it was the the `hook wp` but not.

Thanks for help

Comment: Why do you need to flush rewrite rules periodically?

Comment: @JacobPeattie, 5mn is just for testing purpose, the context :  i had an issue with Polylang Pro plugin, sometimes , when switching language i had 404 error and it's always Intermittent, never same page, really random. So i temporarily fix with resaving permalinks. That 's with i'd like to make wp_schedule_event, while i can debug (maybe causing by a 3rd party plugins)